# Why isn't there is any section for natural language processing (NLP)?

Tags: discussion, support

While searching for answers on Stack Exchange, I've noticed that a lot of [natural language processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) (NLP) questions reside on Stack Overflow, [Linguistics](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/about) or any corresponding language site.

I assume a lot of people, just like me ask questions on natural language processing in the Stack Overflow section, when it is not correct to do so. NLP is not only concerned with programming. This is a separate well-formed field of knowledge that requires a separate Q&A site. Bewildering the fact that [English Language and Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/about) exists together with [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/about) as well as a lot of other unnecessary spinoffs like "*Physical Fitness*" and "*Sport*" and no site for NLP...

NLP questions may be scattered all over the place. I have several questions on the subject and I feel like posting on several Q&A sites because currently none is appropriate.

1. Who and how do we create a site for a particular topic on Stack Exchange?
2. When shall NLP become a separate Q&A site?

Comment: What's wrong with Linguistics as a place for stuff like this?

Comment: I agree, I created an NLP proposal, but as spirc mentioned it got closed. I personally use http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language for algo questions, SO for coding issues, DS for question in between.

Comment: @NickStauner, do you think linguists could answer questions about such things like LSTM, attention networks and deep learning (currently state-of-the-art approaches in NLP)?

Comment: I've started another: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/119217/natural-language-processing

At a conference recently there was too much going on that was the same that others were not aware of.

Comment: @AER what happened to your proposal?

Comment: Deleted, I may have ran out of time to do anything further on it.

Answer (score 9):

Attempts have been made to start Machine Learning and [Natural Language Processing](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74384/natural-language-processing) sites, it looks like this one is the current best candidate, in beta as at Nov 2015.

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As at Feb 2015, that proposal has been deleted.

Comment: Any idea where nlp-related questions should be asked?

Comment: Down-voting because - unfortunately - the answer is not relevant anymore because the link is dead.

Comment: @BramVanroy I have found a new stackexchange for this.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I removed my down-vote.

Comment: @spirc http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/natural-language also welcome NLP questions. DS overlaps a lot with stats.

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to be what we're looking for
https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-linguistics

Comment: Computational linguistics is a different beast. Same principles, different methods.